# ANDROID: How to ensure the user inputs a specific string into edit text?

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

I'm making an app that's based on question and answers, and the answers have typed in by the user and have to be accurate. How do I set up edit text to show that the answer provided by the user is valid, and if it's valid, I want a dialog box to appear with buttons continue and retry!

Comment: What you're asking for is more or less basic understanding of java/android. Please research some more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You an use `TextWatcher` for checking answer enter by user is valid or not.as

```
mEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ET);
mEditText.addTextChangedListener(mTextWatcher);
TextWatcher mTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
        private CharSequence temp;
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
            temp = s;
        }
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
         //CHECK HERE if answer is valid or not
        }
    };
```

Comment: Thanks! But I used check.content equals instead! It Works fine! :D

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do would be to use a regex pattern, and ensure the text within the textbox matches the pattern. [Here's a good piece of documentation that I used to do this.](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)